# Azure Active Directory App Roles for Native App

Tags: ios, azure, azure-active-directory

I have successfully registered both my web api and native app with Azure AD. I can authorise my native app and access the secured web api.

My question is about App Roles, I can't seem to find a way to add App Roles to a native app registration and then assign them to users.

This seems possible for web apps but not for native apps.

I am using the ADALiOS library, if that helps.

Any suggestions about how to get role claims into my token would be appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

App Roles need to be defined on the resource(which needs protected access) and not on the client, so in your case you need to set this on your web api. You can follow this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims) to set it.